# while opeing tor browser getting "/usr/bin/env: ‘./Browser/execdesktop’: Permission denied" error

Tags: browser, tor

[image: See image]

while opeing tor browser getting "/usr/bin/env: ‘./Browser/execdesktop’: Permission denied" error